# How to migrate getter function in class based component to functional component?

Tags: reactjs, migration, react-component, react-functional-component

I'm trying to migrate my class based component to functional component.

keep getting struggles on change **getter / static** methods , how can I achieve these?

```js
// class based component

class Example extends Component {
  ... 
  flag = Math.random * 1 + 1; 
  get someGetter(){
    return flag
  }
  usingGetter(){
    if(this.someGetter) console.log("using Getter called! ");
  }
  static someStatic(){
    console.log("this is some static function" );
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: there is no "silver bullet", use multi-editing feature in your IDE

Answer (score 0):

just convert it to normal variable, you dont need it as class member

```
const someGetter = () => flag
usingGetter () {
  if (someGetter()) console.log("using Getter called! ");
}
```